# Confusing TypeScript error when TSX component imports JSX component with forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

I'm gradually migrating my codebase from JSX to TSX. Unfortunately I get strange errors when my TSX component imports a JSX component with a forwardRef:

> Type '{ children: string; ref: RefObject; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes'.
> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes'.ts(2322)

```
// Test.tsx
import React from 'react'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'

export default function Test() {
    const ref = React.createRef()
    return (
        <div>
            <MyComponent ref={ref}>test</MyComponent>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The `Test.tsx` imports the legacy `MyComponent.jsx`:

```
// MyComponent.jsx
import React from 'react'

const MyComponent = React.forwardRef(({ children }, ref) => {
    return <div ref={ref}>{children}</div>
})

MyComponent.displayName = 'MyComponent'

export default MyComponent
```

How should I fix the TypeScript error (without migrating the legacy MyComponent to TypeScript)?

Note that I don't get the error when the JSX component doesn't use `forwardRef`.

Comment: You would probably have to define a module

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I added a `global.d.ts` to the root of my project, but that didn't help.

Comment: As my problem seems to be quite specific and might be related to my webpack or tsconfig setup, I've decided to totally separate my TSX from JSX. That way I'm sure the 2 folders don't interfere. 

If a new TypeScript component imports a legact JSX-component I either rewrite the JSX component to TSX, or - if that's too much work - still write the new component in JSX.